# How to get a list of all human morphogens?

Tags: gene, database, sequence-annotation, ontology

Gene Ontology provides many genes annotated as taking part in various morphogenesis processes but I want to get a list of all morphogen coding genes specifically. Uniprot  does not have "morphogen" keyword.

I need some gene annotation database that has genes labeled as "morphogen".